The Edit button in my spring boot api does not work. An unexpected error has occurred (type=Not found, status=404)
I have two methods for the button in my MainController:
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editUser(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("userEntity", userService.findById(id));
        return "edit";
    }
    @PutMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public UserEntity editUser(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
        return userService.updateUser(id);
    }

Update method in my UserService:
public UserEntity updateUser(@RequestParam Long id) {
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepo.findById(id).get();
        userEntity.setName(userEntity.getName());
        userEntity.setPassword(userEntity.getPassword());
        return userRepo.save(userEntity);
    }

edit.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/edit}" method="post" th:object="${userEntity}">
    <div><label> New username : <input th:field="*{name}" type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> New password: <input th:field="*{password}" type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Save"></div>
</form>
<a href="/">Return to main page</a>
</body>
</html>

I can not understand in any way why the Whitelabel Error Page error occurs, it does not display an error in the console. On the page he writes There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
I tried to watch the guides (I'm new to Spring), but everyone has Update methods written differently. And I'm also not sure about @PostMapping, whether it needs to be added to the MainController or not, if necessary, how

you don't have a POST method for /edit. You have GET edit/{id} and PUT edit/{id}. 404 is correcty telling you no such endpoint found

If I write a POST, will I need a PUT ? or it can be removed

You need to use @PostMapping if you submit a HTML form. Because it doesn't support a method PUT. However, you can use Postman to make a PUT request. The POST method is used to submit a new user, because it has not yet id. If you want update an existing user, then you should add id to the form.
@PostMapping("/update")
    public UserEntity updateUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        return userService.updateUser(id);
    }

The html form
<form th:action="@{/update}" method="post" th:object="${userEntity}">
    <div><label> New username : <input th:field="*{name}" type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> New password: <input th:field="*{password}" type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Save"></div>
    <input th:field="*{id}" type="hidden" name="id"/>
</form>


Thank you more, I rewrote my update meth in UserService a little bit and added everything there now. And thanks for writing me the html form, I didn't have the input field.

Currently you are sending POST request to the Spring. Your controller does not include endpoint, that supports POST requests (@PostMapping), that is why 404 error appears.
If you want to create new entity and save it to database, you should use other endpoint with POST request mapping.
If you want to update existing entity, it is more conventional to use PUT request with PUT mapping.

I want to update an existing entity, but I do not know how to do it, I tried to change in edit.html method="put" but nothing has changed
